# Increase one more dimension of the vector or matrix in R

Tags: python, r

In Python, we have a function called `np.newaxis`, which increase one more dimension of the original array. I am just wondering if there are any same functionality in R. For example it will return row vector or column vector if I have a plain vector.

I am trying to convert the Python code into R, here is an example:

```
delta_weights_i_h += hidden_error_term * X[:,None]
delta_weights_h_o += output_error_term * hidden_outputs[:,None]
```

I don't really know how to convert `X[:, None]` into R

Thanks for any help !

Comment: a vector is already a column vector in R.. So what do you mean increase the dimension? If you have a 2*3 matrix for example , what will be results in python?

Comment: @Onyambu: Yea, for 2 dimension (2,3), I want it become 3 dimension (2, 1, 3)

Comment: You might take a look at the `abind` package

Comment: If `dim(m)` gives (say) `[1] 4 3`, then `dim(m) <- c(4,3,1)` will add a dimension, though it still only has 12 elements. From there, you'll need to use something like @Renu's `abind` to add layers to it.

Comment: In general, `dim(m) = c(dim(m), 1)` will add a dimension to `m` (need to start with 2 at least, vectors only have length, not dimension). But if you want the new dimension to go in the middle somewhere you'll have to specify or define some logic for where it goes.

Comment: What about if the dimension is `c(2,3,4)`?, do you want it as `c(2,1,3,4)` or `c(2,3,1,4)`?

Comment: I wonder if `array` could come handy here. It would probably help if you had an actual (incl. border case) example.

Comment: @Onyambu I guess it depends where u put the `None` in the matrix slicing.

Comment: then `a=function(x){ if(!is.array(x)) return(as.matrix(x)); 
  \`dim<-\`(x,c(dim(x)[1],1,tail(dim(x),-1)))}` should work.. Try it on a vector etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If X is a vector, then you can add a dimension using `dim()` and `length()` functions

```
X <- 1:5
X
##[1] 1 2 3 4 5

dim(X) <- c(length(X), 1)
X
##     [,1]
##[1,]    1
##[2,]    2
##[3,]    3
##[4,]    4
##[5,]    5
```

If X is a matrix or an array with more than 2 dimensions and you want to add axis to be the second dimension:

```
X <- matrix(1:6, ncol=2)
X
##     [,1] [,2]
##[1,]    1    4
##[2,]    2    5
##[3,]    3    6

dim(X) <- c(dim(X)[1], 1, dim(X)[-1])
dim (X)
##[1] 3 1 2


X
#, , 1
#
#     [,1]
#[1,]    1
#[2,]    2
#[3,]    3
#
#, , 2
#
#     [,1]
#[1,]    4
#[2,]    5
#[3,]    6
```

Comment: How do you add a dimension different than `1`? For example, this command `dim(X) <- c(dim(X)[1], 2, dim(X)[-1])`, gives `dims [product 704643072] do not match the length of object [117440512]` error. The specific numbers are probably specific to my dataset.